# I'm getting an error when i delete value in a array Python

Tags: python, indexoutofrangeexception

`i am getting an error when i run the following code:

```
dosya=open("a.txt","r").read()
dosya=dosya.split(" ")
uzun=len(dosya)
sayac=[0 for i in range(len(dosya))]
for i in range(uzun):
    for j in range(i+1,uzun):
        if(dosya[i]==dosya[j]):
            del dosya[j]
            sayac[i]+=1
    sayac[i]+=1
    del dosya[i]
    i+=1
print sayac
```

`

> Erorr : IndexError: list index out of range

why ? and how can i fix it

Comment: When you delete an element from `dosya`, it gets smaller, so the larger indices are no longer valid.

Comment: yes. how can i fix

Comment: Loop downwards from the end of the list so that the items you remove don't change the parts of the list you not yet examined.

Answer (score 0):

```
dosya=open("a.txt","r").read()
dosya=dosya.split(" ")
uzun=len(dosya)
sayac=[0 for i in range(len(dosya))]
for i in range(uzun):
    for j in range(i+1,uzun):
        if(dosya[i]==dosya[j] and dosya[i]!=""):
            #del dosya[j]
            dosya[j] = ""
            sayac[i] += 1
    sayac[i] += 1
    #del dosya[i] since you've already parsed it. No need of deleting it.
    #i+=1   Since i will automatically increment.
print sayac
```

I think your program is to count number of occurences of each word. Bad logic.

Comment: I'm new to coding. Thank you,i impressed

Answer (score 0):

In the future please explain the intent of your code. It helps if you provide an example input and what should be the output. As @Learner1947 points out it looks like you are trying to count how often each token (i.e., word) occurs. This is easily done using the `collections.Counter` class.

```
import collections

dosya = "abc def ghi abc ghi jkl mno def def"
dosya = dosya.split(" ")
counts = collections.Counter(dosya)
print counts
print counts['def']
print counts['abc']
```

That yields this result for me:

```
Counter({'def': 3, 'abc': 2, 'ghi': 2, 'jkl': 1, 'mno': 1})
3
2
```